# Why is .scrollLeft not working in a timeout function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of script in which I managed to make the mousewheel event move the page horizontally instead of vertically. But I also wanted to add some momentum to it. I created the "after" function but the `.scrollLeft` for body won't run.

```
var rate = 150;

$(function () {
    $("body").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
        function after() {
            $("body").scrollLeft -= (delta * 1000);
            console.log(delta);
            event.preventDefault();
        };

        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * rate);
        event.preventDefault();

        setTimeout(function () {
            after(delta, event)
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

The way I see it, after 3 seconds the body should move with `(delta * 1000)` speed but it does not for some reason.

Comment: your 'after' function doesn't take any arguments?

Comment: it does, the `console.log` in the after function was made specifically to see if it gets the parameters. First iteration of the script wasn't correct in that sense(hence the edit)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would work(not sure)

```
var rate = 150;

$(function () {
$("body").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
    function after(event, delta) {
        $("body").scrollLeft -= (delta * 1000);
        console.log(delta);
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * rate);
    event.preventDefault();

    setTimeout(function () {
        after(event, delta)
    }.bind(null,event, delta), 3000);
});
});
```

Comment: Sadly, it didn't. The `console.log` in the 2nd function still displays delta like it did before, but to no avail. I ruled out delta not existing in the 2nd function so I'm all out of issues :(